# Unable to spy html element on a website

Tags: blueprism, rpa

I am trying to spy a navigation button which drops a dropdown menu when hovers upon. I am having trouble highlighting what I have identified.

I ran IE's DOM explorer (F12) to identify the the HTML element. It is around the tags viewed on DOM explorer: html/body/div/form/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/a.

Currently I have these attributes:

- Element Type: HTML Element
- Class Name: MainMenu_1 (exact class name of the attribute, manually added)
- Enabled: True (automatically generated)
- Path: /HTML/BODY(1)/DIV(1)/FORM(1)/DIV(4)/DIV(1)/DIV(2)/TABLE(1)/TBODY(1)/TR(1)/TD(1)/TABLE(1)/TBODY(1)/TR(1)/TD(1)/A(1)
  (automatically generated)
- Tag Name: A (automatically generated)
- Parent URL: the website I am connected to (automatically generated)

Are my attributes correctly done? Do I have to add more?
What else do I need to do?

The available attributes are:

- Tag Name
- Path
- Enabled
- X
- Y
- Width
- Value
- Title
- Screen Bounds
- Parent URL
- Match Reverse
- Match Index
- Link
- Input Type
- Input Identifier
- ID
- Height
- Class Name
- Checked
- Ancestor Count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this using Application Modeler >> Identify >> Open Application Navigator. The tool identified and listed every single html elements from the website where I can choose the appropriate element.

Answer (score 0):

un-check parent URL(this creates issues in case of dynamic websites). if there are multiple drop-down menus check the ordinal attribute.

Comment: I have unchecked parent URL. Using just Path, Class Name and Title. There is no Ordinal attribute for this element. I have HTML Element as the Element Type. With Path, Class Name and Title, I am unable to highlight.. any more ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**Hey can you try these attributes in your application modeller,**

- Class Name: MainMenu_1 (exact class name of the attribute, manually
  added
- X attribute(manually added)
- Y attribute(manually added) and,
- Width attribute(manually added)

**Use these attributes it works**

Comment: Thanks with the help, I have contemplated on using X and Y but it feels like giving the static position of the item. sounds wrong to me. I have instead solved this using the Application Navigator.